VSCode Zen Mode: Extend Editor Width (Remove Side Margins)
Within VSCode's Zen Mode (toggled using the View: Toggle Zen Mode option from the command palette), I'd like to ensure that the editor width always fills my entire window.
Current behaviour: it has huge horizontal margins, minimizing the space available for code.
Desired behaviour: full window is taken up by the code editor, with the horizontal margins removed entirely.
Is there a settings file (as shown in screenshot below) configuration or VSCode extension I can use to achieve this result?


Open Command Pallete (Ctrl + Shift + P) > Run Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON) > Add the following to your settings json file:
"zenMode.centerLayout": false

The default layout is centered
